# How to find linearly dependent subsets from a large set of real-valued vectors quickly?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, algorithms, vectors, numerical-linear-algebra

## Problem

I have a set $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, where $n = 600$.
The set of vectors $V$ is big enough: $\left| V \right| \approx 50 \cdot 10^3$.
I want to find $m$-tuples $U_i \subset V$ with linearly **dependent** vectors

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\forall U_i: \exists \alpha^i \neq 0 \in \mathbb{R}^n: \sum\limits_{u \in U_i} u \cdot \alpha^i_u = 0 \\
\left| U_1 \right| = \left| U_2 \right| = \dots = \left| U_m \right|
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

At the moment I've found out manually that I have no linearly dependent pairs, using orthogonal projection and brute force.
For each pair $\left\langle v, u \right\rangle \in V^2$ (pairs mean $\left| U_i \right| = 2$)
I've checked

\begin{equation}
v - \frac{\left( v, u \right)}{\left\| u \right\|^2} \cdot u = 0
\end{equation}

and it was *false* for all pairs.
Also this consumed <s>hours</s> 20 minutes on my laptop: I've needed to check about
$\frac{\left( 50 \cdot 10^3 \right)^2}{2} = 1.25 \cdot 10^9$ pairs.
Similar approach looks impossible for the case of triples ($1.25 \cdot 10^{14}$ items), not saying about quads ($6.25 \cdot 10^{18}$ tuples).

## Details

There were 199 tuples with $50 \cdot 10^3$ 3D vertices each (199 3D scans of faces), which were analyzed with PCA in order to have a generative face model.
As result I've got set of $50 \cdot 10^3$ vectors.
Each vector contains average position and principal components coefficients of corresponding vertex.

I'm working on method, which uses this information, and it needs triples of vertices, in which offset coefficients are linearly dependent and average positions are not.
This means, that I have $n = 597$, not $600$, but does it mean for an algorithm?

Sure, I can use not all coefficients, for example $50$ from each dimension, which will give me $\mathbb{R}^{150}$.
Though, I'm working on generic approach and in another case number of dimensions can be bigger.

## Question

Is there a fast algorithm for finding at least all triples and quads of linearly **dependent** vectors from a given set in multidimensional space (hundreds of dimensions)?

Obviously, storage of an ordinary computer cannot store all possible tuples and algorithm has to give solution by chunks.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^{600}$ there are at most 600 linearly independent vectors, so your set of 50,000 vectors has mostly linearly dependent vectors in it. You could use the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to find the basis. However, the *"of the same length"* throws me off: do you mean you only wish to consider tuples where the vectors have the same length, or that all your vectors already are of the same length?

Comment: Also, "hours" sounds like inefficient coding (if you use Linux, I might be able to help with some better code). Why not start by calculating the 50000×50000 symmetric real matrix of normalized dot products (i.e., cosines between each pair of vectors)? If you find 600 $i$ where $u_i \cdot u_j = 0$, $i \ne j$, you have identified a basis, and all the other vectors are their linear combinations.

Comment: @NominalAnimal

I know that I can find the basis of $600$ linearly independent vectors by nature of my set, but I don't need it.

I've noted in equation that $\left| U_i \right|$ should be equal -- I wanted to find all linearly dependent pairs and got none. Then I want to find triples and quads. Maybe this sounds strange, but if you want to know why I need this, I can send you several articles to read and explain the idea - this may take a week :)

Maybe I've got *hours* because of inefficient coding. Though, the problem seems to have exponential complexity and this confuses me.

Comment: How about some combination of [kd-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) and a dimensionality reduction like [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis)?

Comment: If your vectors are uniformly distributed on a 599-d hypersphere, then there almost certainly won't be any linearly dependent subsets of size up to $600$. At $601$ there'll be a sudden jump from no linearly dependent sets to every set being linearly dependent.

Comment: @Charlie: Why not? My email is shown on my home page linked to from my profile. I like to help others do research, as my own focus is in developing better research tools like simulators and such. Here, I can imagine a multithreaded SSE/AVX implementation should be able to cut the time needed to calculate the pairwise dot products to a fraction of what you described, on your machine. Plus sometimes, there is an alternative way (algorithmic optimization!) to achieve the same result. I won't promise anything, though.

Comment: @jkabrg: Well expressed. On the other hand, even if the set is roughly uniformly distributed, there could be some underlying structure (for example, 98% of the vectors being random, but 2% or 1000 vectors having clear structure) that might pop up at smaller subsets (say, 3 to 6 vector subsets). The question is, *how to efficiently determine if such subsets exist*? A secondary question is, what such subsets tell us about the set of vectors.

Comment: @NominalAnimal thanks, I've sent the details on your e-mail. Yes, one of the problems is to efficiently determine if such subsets exist. I've asked about existence of some fast generic algorithm for finding such subsets instead of checking each tuple. If it's the only way to do this, I will work on computations optimization and the question may be closed as the problem is NP-Hard (is it?).

Comment: @jkabrg FYI I've added more details to the question

Comment: Someone has mentioned PCA. It also reminds me of Nonnegative matrix factorization.

Comment: Look at collision detection in computer games. k-d trees (for $k = 3$) are used for that. I don't know if it's practical to use $k$-d trees for $k = 600$. If it's not, you can preprocess the data further using PCA.

Comment: @jkabrg as I've mentioned, this data is already a PCA output and I can use $150$-dimensional vectors in this case. Nevertheless another set may contain more dimensions and I want to know whether it's possible to solve the problem for feasible time with hundreds of dimensions and tuples of more than $2$ vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comment is a bit too long, I will write that as an answer, and delete it afterwards.
Maybe it helps you, maybe it is completely wrong.

I understand your question in the following way:

Given a set of vectors $V$ find all possible m-tuple $U⊂V$, with $2≤m≤600$, of linear dependant vectors.

Here are two possible optimization to the brute force algorithm:

1. Linear dependence [l.d.] of two vectors is transitive:

   If $v_1$ and $v_2$ are l.d. and $v_2$ and $v_3$ are l.d. than  $v_1$ and $v_3$ are l.d.

   ⇒ You can build equivalence classes of l.d. vectors.

   ⇒ Here with only two vectors ($v_1, v_2$) in your equivalence class, you save 1 calculation. If you already now your equivalence class contains $m$ vectors, you save $m-1$ calculations.

   I am currently not sure if that can be generalised to sets of vectors.
2. If you want to know if $2$ vectors $u,v∈ℝ^n$ are linear *in*dependant, it is enough to check if the following $2×2$-matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix} u_1 & v_1 \\ u_2 & v_2 \end{pmatrix}$$ with the first two components, has full rank (=is invertible).

   - If yes, then $u$ and $v$ are linear *in*dependant, and thus not l.d.
   - If no, you can't say anything.
   - $m$ vectors ⇒ $m×m$ matrix

Does this help?

edit: I just had a thought about your check:
$$v−\frac{(v,u)}{∥u∥^2}\cdot u==0$$

Are your vectors from experimental / computational data? If so this will never ever be ==0. Rather check $≤10^{−8}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, you've understood the question properly. 
Your second approach is what I've got on my mind this morning and I've faced such issue that rank of matrix is affected not only by linearly dependent rows, but by linearly dependent columns as well.
Thank you for mention of computational accuracy. Though, I guess, you've meant $\min\limits_{v \in V} \left| v \right| \cdot 10^{-8}$. Seems like there is no general approach for this problem.

Comment: Regarding generalization of transitivity for the case of tuples with more than $2$ elements I've got some thoughts. Let's choose a vector $u \in V$ and construct new set $V' = \left\{ v - proj_u\left(v\right) \; \middle| \; v \in V, v \neq u \right\}$. In new set $V'$ we can check linear dependency of pairs of vectors, it will be transitive and will take into account projection on the "basic" vector $u$. We can generalize this for arbitrary amount of basic vectors. Nevertheless I have no idea how to use this yet.

Comment: @Charlie No, I do mean $\|v−\frac{(v,u)}{∥u∥^2}\cdot u \|≤10^{-8}$, because that term will never be equal to $0$. [Try it online](https://tio.run/##XY07DsIwEET7nMLlruWEfBBVfBJEsRYSGMUf2U7h05tNgQRUO3rzRhtreQa/tGZdDKkIv7tYBWXhY9eR0HwHSokqXGe13LAzP@ysLsxiCi/GJHoB3N1DAVIGT5w362l7DD4kBwalnFEa9q0vkHcHxxLxH2g9ftjxyuQvd9XTKGU/sdHaGw) for a simple example of two linear dependant vectors.

Comment: If I use bigger numbers and convert them to floating point, this epsilon becomes very small --
 just [try it online](https://tio.run/##Xc07DoMwDAbgnVN4I4kCDVAxNSepOjiiDyryUAhDTp@aoVLpYlu/P8shp5d3QymzDT4mcJsNGXAFF6oKQVNvMUbM7NrL4SZhSjncdf2oeWUO67NSSo5UjihE/yaH0AAjPPnEUBp@onmZHS7P1vlomeFC9FwY8rNLbN0s2y85/w@0Vt9s/23WH3vRnRKi6UiU8gE).
Anyway, I've got your remark, thank you for that. I hoped that there exists an algorithm or even simple formula which solves my problem